# Embed a Google Sheet as you view it in a separate tab?

Tags: plugins, database, google-docs

Is it possible to embed a Google Sheet as you view it in a separate tab like in [this website](http://blog.goodnessbee.com/2015/02/natural-eczema-treatments-what-actually-works.html)?

[image: image description]

I have tried to use [Publish to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=en) or the plugin [Inline Google Spreadsheet Viewer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer/faq/) but it just embed a simple sheet. My file has various sheets and lots of data so it will be great if visitors can make some complex action such as filtering or sorting.

Comment: It looks like it's just an iframe with the spreadsheet URL set as the source

Comment: Have you tried setting "Who has access" to "Anyone with the link"?

Comment: @TomJNowell that's so easy. Make it an answer and I will accept yours. Sorry for the trivial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an iframe in your post content, and set its source as the google spreadsheet! You'll probably want to create a shortcode for iframes as they're stripped out of post content automatically, but there are questions asking how to do that on this site